# How to define a Java Map in graphql?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, maps, graphql-java

I have a `filterModel` which is a Map `Map<String, ColumnFilter> filterModel` in order to filter my Actor data. I get an filterModel Object from the client when I try to filter my data. How do I define this Java Map in my graphql Query?

filterModel Object from client:

```
filterModel: {
               firstname: {filterType: 'text', type: 'contains', filter: 'Tom'}, ...
              }
```

schema:

```
type Actor {
    actorId: ID!,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
}

type Query {
    rows(
        filterModel: [filterModel]
    ): [Actor]
}

input filterModel {
    key: String,
    value: ColumnFilter
}

input ColumnFilter {
    filterType: String,
    type: String,
    filter: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no map type in GraphQL. Because maps are basically containing dynamic keys and, they do not play well into the static types that GraphQL is expecting.

If you are really unsure of what type the data is going to be in that map, you can always store that dynamic information as a String. This is something I personally would do.

So your filterModel would become
`filterModel:String` and that string would be a `JSON` representation of the object. You can do the JSON parsing in the code to convert it back to a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

0 input

```
mutation{ xxxx(employeeBean:{ xxxxx , attributes: {\"key\":\"value\"}" }) {
xxxxxxx attributes }}
```

1.schema file

```
scalar JSON
type Employee {
   
   ........
   attributes: JSON
}
```

1.configuration

```
@Bean
public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
    return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder
            .scalar(jsonScalar());
}

public GraphQLScalarType jsonScalar() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
            .name("JSON") //graphql type define in the schema file
            .description("Java MAP as scalar.")
            .coercing(new Coercing<Map<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String serialize(final Object dataFetcherResult) {
                    if (dataFetcherResult instanceof Map) {
                        try {
                            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataFetcherResult);
                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new CoercingSerializeException("Expected a Map object.");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> parseValue(final Object input) {

                    if (input instanceof StringValue) {
                        try {
                            return objectMapper.readValue(input.toString()
                                    , new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
                                    });


                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new CoercingParseValueException("Expected a String");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> parseLiteral(final Object input) {
                    if (input instanceof StringValue) {
                        try {
                            return objectMapper.readValue(((StringValue) input).getValue()
                                    , new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
                                    });
                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new CoercingParseLiteralException("Expected a StringValue.");
                    }
                }
            }).build();

}
```

3 bean

```
public class EmployeeBean {

private Map<String,String> attributes;
}
```

### Note

GraphQlArgumentBinder-> public Object bind(
DataFetchingEnvironment environment, @Nullable String argumentName, ResolvableType targetType)
throws BindException {}
not able to bind the value to the map object because its using map name define in the schema and then put dot and then the first key name and searching of that name in the bean to find the map and its not working as of now